# "To which", "by which", "on which" etc

Tags: expressions, prepositions, relative-pronouns, pied-piping

I have come across the phrases like "to which","for which", "by which", "on which" and so on(using a preposition with a relative pronoun).

e.g. The chair on which the body was found..

Could someone please explain if there's a particular rule to be followed when building/using them?

Can I use any preposition before 'which'? 
What if I say "The chair which the body was found on"?
How would I decide which preposition to be put?
Can I use other relative pronouns too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but I don't understand the confusion here. Use the preposition that means what you intend. If the body is lying on a chair, it is the chair *on which* the body was found. If the body is on the ground next to the chair, it is the chair *by which* the body was found. What other "rule" could apply?

Answer (score 5):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_relative_clauses#Relative_pronoun_as_the_object_of_a_preposition) contains [blended with previous version]:

> **Relative pronoun as the object of a preposition**
>
> A relative pronoun often appears as the object of a preposition. For
>   formal writing or speech any relative pronoun serving as an object
>   must be one that 'takes' the objective case, for example, *whom,
>   whose,* or *which*, but usually not *who* and never *that*—both *who*
>   and *that* usually take the subjective case:
>
> *Jack is the boy with whom Jenny fell in love* (formal)
>
> *Jack built the house in which I was raised* (formal)
>
> but not
>
> *Jack is the boy with who Jenny fell in love* (colloquial; or not okay)
>
> and never
>
> *Jack built the house in that I was raised* (not okay).
>
> In modern, especially informal, English it is not unusual to move the
>   preposition to the end of the relative clause (as though for an
>   independent clause) while leaving the relative pronoun at the
>   beginning of the clause, or omitting it. Such preposition-stranding
>   (or 'dangling' the preposition) has traditionally been deemed
>   unacceptable by grammarians for formal style. Still, the ‘stranded
>   preposition’ form has been widely used since Old English times, and is
>   normal in colloquial speech. Here is the formal style:
>
> *Jack is the boy with whom Jenny fell in love* (formal);
>
> but any of the following might be heard in ordinary (including
>   colloquial) speech:
>
> *Jack is the boy whom Jenny fell in love with* (not formal);
>
> *Jack is the boy Jenny fell in love with* (not formal);
>
> *Jack is the boy who Jenny fell in love with* (colloquial);
>
> *Jack is the boy that Jenny fell in love with* (colloquial).

Answer (score 1):

A relative clause has a relative expression which comes first in the relative clause, or if not already first, is moved to first position. A relative expression is a noun phrase containing a relative pronoun, or a conjunction of relative expressions.  E.g., with brackets around the relative expressions,

> the book [which] I bought
>   the book [[the bottom cover of which] and [whose left front corner]] had been burnt

This is a rough outline of the treatment in **Generalized Phrase Structure Grammar** by Gazdar, Klein, Pullum, and Sag, and omits important constraints (because I can't remember the details).