# "By which" with another "by"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

There is a posted question about prepositions: ["To which", "by which", "on which" etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234453/to-which-by-which-on-which-etc). I could not add a comment because I have not had 50 reputations yet, so I decided to post another question.

> It is the mechanism by which hospitals are reimbursed by Medicare.

I don't understand why there is *by* before the *which,* and why this *by* is added when there is already a *by* after the *reimbursed.*

Comment: +1 For being new and realizing a new question was the route to take.

Comment: Medicare reimburses hospitals by the Hell-Volhard-Huddleston mechanism. <==> The Hell-Volhard-Huddleston mechanism is the mechanism by which Medicare reimburses hospitals (_or_ ... the mechanism by which hospitals are reimbursed by Medicare). Leaving out the source of the reimbursements, one still needs 'by which':  The Hell-Volhard-Huddleston mechanism is the mechanism by which hospitals are reimbursed.

Answer (score 2):

"By" is a preposition in English that is frequently used to replace the *instrumental* case in Old English.

> instrumental case: this case is expressed by inflection in Old English, Sanskrit, Russian, etc., and in English with the prepositions by or with (Ex.: OE ðȳ spere, “by the spear, with the spear”) [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/instrumental)

With the collapse of the declension  system in English, beginning a thousand years ago, prepositions were required to express the function of a noun or pronoun.

> It is the mechanism by which hospitals are reimbursed by Medicare.

Hospitals are reimbursed . The means of this reimbursement is the mechanism; "which" refers to the  mechanism.
"Which" (mechanism) can be thought of as the *instrument* of reimbursement . 
This sentence could be writen differently:

> By this mechanism  hospitals are reimbursed by Medicare.

"Which" is gone.
So long as "which" is present, referring to "mechanism". the "by" is required to indicate the *instrumental* nature of "mechanism".

Without the "by":

> It is the mechanism  which hospitals are reimbursed by Medicare.

The "by" might be understood, but it might not . The second "by"  (by Medicare) is a separate *instrumental* unrelated to "by which".

Comment: The second "by" is part of the passive construction.

Comment: Greg Lee -----Yes, the second "by" is integral to  "are reimbursed", the action of the hospital being passive, "by Medicare" is the instrument of   reimbursement.....if one wishes to see it that way. I'm sure many modern grammarians frown.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a simple answer.

> It is the mechanism by which hospitals are reimbursed by Medicare.

Related:

> Hospitals are reimbursed by Medicare by some certain mechanism.

The first part is the passive voice, equivalent to "Medicare reimburses hospitals."

The second part, "by some mechanism" could be restated as "through some mechanism."